# CiviCRM Administration areas unreachable even by direct link

Tags: administer

I am setting up and configuring a new CiviCRM/Drupal 7 installation for a local business and have installed the latest of both. I have inserted a very small amount of data and configured the event calendar (views only)
Going through the settings for localisation etc. I encountered an error were CiviCRM warned that the attachment size could not be more than php size. I altered this to the correct value, clicked save and:

I cannot access any admin link, no CiviCRM menu and the direct links are also not doing anything.
Normally okay at debugging these things but I'm at a loss. Can anyone help?

```
misc?reset=1:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://###/civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US?cid=2&r=Tx80w' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Common.js?q73rge:1517 Error: CRM.url called before initialization
CRM.console @ Common.js?q73rge:1517
CRM.url @ crm.ajax.js?q73rge:19
initialize @ crm.menubar.js?q73rge:18
(anonymous) @ crm.menubar.js?q73rge:491
(anonymous) @ crm.menubar.js?q73rge:493

crm.ajax.js?q73rge:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'back' of undefined
    at Object.CRM.url (crm.ajax.js?q73rge:26)
    at Object.initialize (crm.menubar.js?q73rge:18)
    at crm.menubar.js?q73rge:491
    at crm.menubar.js?q73rge:493
CRM.url @ crm.ajax.js?q73rge:26
initialize @ crm.menubar.js?q73rge:18
(anonymous) @ crm.menubar.js?q73rge:491
(anonymous) @ crm.menubar.js?q73rge:493

misc?reset=1:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Answer (score 3):

Feel like an idiot now:

Used an old trick by visiting /civicrm/menu/rebuild?reset=1

Appears fixed. No browser errors!